# Should GET requests store to database?

Tags: php, web, http-post, http-get

I’ve read that you should not use GET requests if you are modifying the database. How would you record analytics about your website then?

For example, I want to record page views whenever someone visits a page. I would need to update `views = views + 1` in the database. Is this OK, despite using a GET request, or is there another technique? Surely, not every request should be a POST request.

Comment: Well typically that's not a separate request, and will be done in the background. You'll just have to assume that you're going to get repeated counts from people moving through their browser history and such. Not such a big deal for unimportant purposes like this.

Comment: @miken32 What I mean is if the user navigates to “/home”. In the background is it ok to update the view count in the database despite the http request being GET /home. Because I was under the impression that if you update the database it should be a POST request, but POST /home doesn’t make sense.

Comment: As I said, the view count isn't the point of the request, it's incidental to the user visiting the page. The method is irrelevant in this case; the advice not to use the GET method for requests that will make changes refers to the primary purpose of viewing the page. E.g. creating an account, making a purchase, editing a file – these are actions that should be done as POST.

Comment: @miken32 this answers my question. Thanks

Comment: @miken32 if you submit this as an answer I’ll mark it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general advice about how to use POST vs. GET shows up in [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-8.3) from 23 years ago:

> The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI.

> POST is designed to allow a uniform method to cover the following functions:
>
> - Annotation of existing resources;
> - Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list, or similar group of articles;
> - Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a form [3], to a data-handling process;
> - Extending a database through an append operation.

These guidelines remain in effect to this day, but they cover the primary purpose of the user's page request.

The act of incrementing a view counter is incidental to the **primary purpose** of the request, which is to view the page content. Indeed, the user is likely unaware that this database update is occurring.

(Of course, you must expect that you will receive duplicate requests as users move through browser history, caches are populated, or spiders crawl your pages. This wouldn't be the case if a POST request was made.)

Answer (score 0):

It's ok.

When you make POST request, you actually wait for POST params to come and you build your database insert query based on parameters which you've got from browser.
On GET request you actually implement your own business logic, so user won't ever know what is going on the side.

And for the finish, actually sometimes you can do something, what's going against rules, rules are good, but we are able not to follow them, that's what makes us human, if we would strictly follow all the rules, it would be cumbersome.